# ASP.NET Web API 2 with Websockets

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, websocket

We are currently looking into refactoring our backend service layer and start using ASP.NET WEB Api instead of WCF mostly due to the fact that WebAPI is a better solution for simple Rest communication. However, we also need to be able to update the client browser window when something happens in backend that needs to be communicated. Hence the need for WebSockets or something similar.

My question: would my MVC 5 Web Api controllers need to be changed? When searching on google it seems like I would be able to simply add WebSockets Controllers alongside with the Web API controllers to make the bidirectional communication work, is that true?

Comment: I haven't heard of "WebSockets Controllers" before, but If you need to push realt-time content from the server to the client you should use SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr . Usually, you'll start by implementing a Hub, something that is not an ApiController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "pure" WebSockets aren't a requirement I can recommend using SignalR together with WebAPI 2 (they really really make a tremendous web stack!). There are several good tutorials as this cast: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Belgium-2013/25

One critical point to understand are the different life-times of controllers / hubs etc...

---

Edit:
One aspect you may want to read about is on how to call SignalR Hub methods from your Controller: And it's rather easy to interact with Hubs from Controllers, here's some reading about that: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

Comment: ok, I had a look at some parts of the video. Since I'm not using an OData controller, It seem that I can just change Web API Controller to inheri from a "hub"-enabled controller instead of ApiController. Would I be forced to change the web api controller function signatures or would I just add signal R code in the appropriate web api controller functions?

Comment: ok, after having read Augustos comment above; I will need to implement a hub instead in the places where I need birectional communication and stick to regular webapi controllers where I do not..